# Creating a plugin that adds functionality to a theme

Tags: wordpress

Divi is a wordpress theme https://www.elegantthemes.com/gallery/divi/. It contains a video module https://www.elegantthemes.com/gallery/divi/documentation/video/ that allows you to add the URL of your video and then view it on your website. Currently it supports Youtube, Vimeo, etc. however does not support Wistia. Without going into detail Wistia is the only option I can use, and therefore my aim is to create a plugin that adds this functionality. However I'm going into the unknown and want further direction. My first objective would be to look into the theme code and find out how the theme is adding this functionality for Youtube, Vimeo, etc. Exactly how would I find the code? And then why wouldn't this functionality have been added to begin with? Would they have just left it out, or would it be another reason that might be preventing me from adding the functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every single include/embed/attachment etc. that loads from an external source, into Your app is done trough the usage of an **[API](http://www.webopedia.com/TERM/A/API.html)** which Your source provides.

You won't be able to find much in their code since this is probably being done trough some custom shortcodes or hooks. In both situations, this requires custom modifications from their developers in order for the Westia API to work with the DIVI builder.

In Your particular case, **[Westia do provide an API](https://wistia.com/doc/player-api)**  but if DIVI didn't include that yet, I presume that this is because of the fact that Westia is a ***[Niche](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/niche)*** video hosting provider, not a public one like Youtube / Vimeo. Therefore, I think that You should contact their support for more information on that issue.

You can try to embed your desired wisita video trough a custom object of some kind.

So in this case, You can go trough **[this thread right here by Elegant themes](https://www.elegantthemes.com/blog/resources/exploring-divi-2-4-using-the-divi-code-module-to-integrate-third-party-plugins-in-the-builder)**, and after you get acquainted with the methods to do so, head over to [**WISTIA's embedding options page**](https://wistia.com/doc/embedding) and find out what fits your site best.

Comment: I have contacted them, however I feel a response may take time. As I need to find a solution asap, is it possible to do the custom shortcode myself as a plugin?

Comment: I think that if there is no module within the DIVI builder itself, You can simply embed the video from WISTIA directly into your content. Please look up in my answer for updated info.

Comment: I have added the wistia wordpress plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/wistia-wordpress-oembed-plugin/. I have then used the Wistia oEmbed URL (as the standard and fallback methods failed https://wistia.com/doc/wordpress). This obviously worked on a random post, so I tried to add the oEmbed URL to the Divi 'Code module' however this also failed. I thought the 'Code module' would replicate the blank content area found when you start a new post / page.

Comment: When you say "embed your desired wistia video through a custom object of some kind", are you sort of referring to creating a shortcode containing something like the Wistia Oembed URL?

Comment: @Vitamin , if you have the time and nerve, turn it into a shortcode, if not, just simply use a custom container provided to You by the DIVI system (see the thread that I posted in the previous comment). To be honest, this is the first time I am seeing the WISTIA system, so I think a simple embed is the way to go.. for now. Until DIVI's team decide to implement such an option for their users. Cheers!

Comment: I can play wistia videos now. Thanks for the help. I've created a new issue though because I have to use a normal slider to enter the oEmbed url. This normal slider has no thumbnail track, however this is a new issue and if I have more trouble I'll create a new post.